# I am trying to install Tensor flow on window 10 with pip install tensor flow but its not working

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried many other commands as well but all in vain.

Here is the error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /tensorflow/window/cpu/tensorflow-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (Caused by ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)"))
```

Please help me.
Looking forward for your responses.

Comment: Are you running ``pip3 install tensorflow``?

Comment: Dear!I tried this as well but same error.

Comment: Would be great if you can help us with the commands that you've tried so that we can understand the behaviours more clearly :)

Comment: Pip install tensorflow,

Comment: I have tried following commands:

Comment: I have tried following commands:

Comment: I have tried following commands:pip install tensorflow,pip3 install tensorflow and few others

Comment: Some time i got this error as well:     ERROR:Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow ERROR:No matching distribution found for tensor flow

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of the error trace that you have mentioned, you seem to be running on a timeout for installation, likely due to a slow internet connection.

The default timeout set on pip is 15 seconds:

```
  --timeout <sec>             Set the socket timeout (default 15 seconds).
```

You can use this timeout flag to override it to a higher value:

```
pip install --timeout=60 tensorflow
```